# nonlinear 3d system

Tags: dynamical-systems, 3d, nonlinear-system, quartics

I am trying to find all the critical points of my 3D Nonlinear System described as follows:

\begin{array}{ll}
\\
\dot{x}_1=\mu-x_1^2+x_3+x_2-2x_1 \quad (1)\\\\
\dot{x}_2=\mu-x_2^2+x_3+x_1-2x_2 \quad (2)\\\\
\dot{x}_3=\mu-x_3^2+x_2+x_1-2x_3 \quad (3)\\
\end{array}

I know that there are at least two critical points such that $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(\pm\sqrt{\mu},\pm\sqrt{\mu},\pm\sqrt{\mu}).$ Now I want to eliminate my variables from each equation.

So for instance when $\dot{x}_1=0 \implies x_3=x_1^2+2x_1-x_2-\mu$ and substituting this into (2) yields
$$\dot{x}_2=x_1^2-x^2_2+3x_1-3x_2$$
Setting this equal to zero gives me the relationship $x_1^2+3x_1=x_2^2+3x_2 \implies x_1=x_2.$

Then putting both these relationships into (3) gives me the quartic equation
$$\dot{x}_3=-x^4_1-2x^3_1+(2\mu-3)x^2_1+2\mu x_1+\mu(3-\mu)$$
When $\mu=2$, I found the roots $(-\sqrt{2},-1,\sqrt{2})$, but I feel as if I should of got four distinct roots than a double root ($-1$ is the double root).

I was wondering if I could get some help solving this generally for any $\mu>0$.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please post the original problem?

Comment: The original problem comes from looking at a how a dynamical variable changes over time on a network described by $\frac{d x_i}{dt}=f(x_i)+\sum_j A_{ij}(x_j-x_i)$, where $f(x_i)=\mu-x_i^2$, $A_{ij}$ is the adjacency matrix of the network. I was looking at the case of a simple graph, with 3 nodes that are all connected by one edge. The system originally posted is specifically written for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference of the first two equations factors as
$$
0=x_2^2-x_1^2+3x_2-3x_1=(x_2-x_2)(x_1+x_2+3)
$$
so that you get two possibilities, $x_2=x_1$ and additionally $x_2=-3-x_1$.

In the difference between the first and the third equation you get the same variants, $x_3=x_1$ or $x_3=-3-x_1$.

Now insert all 4 combinations in the first  of the original equations.

\begin{array}{l|l|ll}
x_2=x_1&x_3=x_1&0=\mu-x_1^2&\implies x_1=x_2=x_3=\pm\sqrt\mu\\\hline
x_2=x_1&x_3=-3-x_1&0=\mu-x_1^2-3-2x_1&\implies x_1=-1\pm\sqrt{\mu-2}\\\hline
x_2=-3-x_1&x_3=-3-x_1&0=\mu-x_1^2-6-4x_1&\implies x_1=-2\pm\sqrt{\mu-2}
\end{array}

Comment: Amazing! I can't believe I didn't spot this, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Solving for $x_1,x_2,x_3$

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \mu-x_1^2-2 x_1+x_2+x_3=0 \\
 \mu-x_2^2-2 x_2+x_1+x_3=0 \\
 \mu-x_3^2-2 x_3+x_1+x_2=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

we have the parameterization

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_1(\mu) & x_2(\mu) & x_3(\mu) \\
 -\sqrt{\mu -2}-2 & \sqrt{\mu -2}-1 & \sqrt{\mu -2}-1 \\
 -\sqrt{\mu -2}-1 & \frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{4 \mu -4 \sqrt{\mu -2}-7}-3\right) & \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{4 \mu -4 \sqrt{\mu -2}-7}-3\right) \\
 -\sqrt{\mu -2}-1 & \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{4 \mu -4 \sqrt{\mu -2}-7}-3\right) & \frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{4 \mu -4 \sqrt{\mu -2}-7}-3\right) \\
 \sqrt{\mu -2}-2 & -\sqrt{\mu -2}-1 & -\sqrt{\mu -2}-1 \\
 \sqrt{\mu -2}-1 & \frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{4 \mu +4 \sqrt{\mu -2}-7}-3\right) & \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{4 \mu +4 \sqrt{\mu -2}-7}-3\right) \\
 \sqrt{\mu -2}-1 & \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{4 \mu +4 \sqrt{\mu -2}-7}-3\right) & \frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{4 \mu +4 \sqrt{\mu -2}-7}-3\right) \\
 -\sqrt{\mu } & -\sqrt{\mu } & -\sqrt{\mu } \\
 \sqrt{\mu } & \sqrt{\mu } & \sqrt{\mu } \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

which parameterize some lines as can be observer in the attached plot

[image]

Now we can try to qualify those points according to the linear theory, inserting those values on

$$
J(x(\mu)) = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -2 x_1(\mu)-2 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & -2 x_2(\mu)-2 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & -2 x_3(\mu)-2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and analyzing the eigenvalues. This is left as an exercise.